# multiple image retrieval from database to file with java

Tags: java

I have been trying to retrieve all images from my table `image` having second column as `image`.The code looks fine but its producing an error `invalid column index`.Please help.

```
package p1;
import java.sql.*;  
import java.io.*;  
public class test 
{  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {  
        try
        {  
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","admin");       
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select image from imagetable");  
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery(); 
            int i=0; 
            while(rs.next())
            {           
                 Blob b=rs.getBlob(2);  
                 byte barr[]=b.getBytes(1,(int)b.length());       
                 FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("d:\\img"+i+".png"); i++; 
                 fout.write(barr);               
                 fout.close();  
             }//end of while  

            System.out.println("ok");                
            con.close();  
         }
         catch (Exception e)    
         {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
         }  
     }  
 }
```

Comment: I think the index is off in Blob b=rs.getBlob(2);, since you are retrieving a single value from each row. try  Blob b=rs.getBlob("image"); instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Blob b=rs.getBlob("image");
```

instead of

```
 Blob b=rs.getBlob(2);
```

the reason for the exception is that you are retrieving a single value, that is why column index is invalid.

Comment: By writing 2,i am specifying that i want to retrieve value from 2nd column.Since it's placed in a loop,i am retrieving single value at one iteration.

Comment: Your welcome. don't forget to mark this answer as correct :)